# Custom post edit page permalink links to edit page rather than the post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Custom post edit page permalink links to edit page rather than the post

Here is how the Recipe custom post was created

```
  register_post_type( 'recipe',
  array(
    'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Recipe' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Recipe' )
    ),
  'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'  => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '','with_front' => true ),
  'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
  'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'post-formats','comments','set_featured_image','thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','custom-fields'),
  'capabilities' => array(
    'edit_post' => 'edit_recipes',
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_recipes',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_recipes',
    'delete_posts' => 'delete_recipes',
        'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_other_recipes',
         'publish_posts' => 'publish_recipes',
    'read_post' => 'read_recipes',
    'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_recipes',
    'delete_post' => 'delete_recipes'
  )
  )
   );

  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Please see the below screenshot of what I mean, how can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Try setting `'rewrite' => false` where you register the CPT, then `unregister_post_type`, then re-register the CPT. It's likely a problem with setting a rewrite then setting slug to empty.

Comment: @WebElaine setting it to false disabled the link http://prntscr.com/h1umta

Comment: You could try giving it a slug instead of setting it to empty.

Comment: I don't see any reason to have this: `flush_rewrite_rules();` is that a shortcut around visiting the permalinks page after initializing the post type?